# Adding dynamic login and logout links rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I have a very basic sign up and log in setup running and all I want to know if how to add a link at the very top of my root page that displays 'Log in' or 'Sign out' depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

I have tried various methods I have found on here but can't seem to get them to work as they often create undefined method errors.

What is the simplest way to create this?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a session variable where you save the id of the current user (i call it user_id) you could do it like this:

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
  <!-- user is logged in -->
  <%= link_to logout_path %>
<% else %>
  <!-- user is not logged in -->
  <%= link_to login_path %>
<% end %>
```

that is what you have to change:

```
config/routes.rb:

resources :users

# login stuff
controller :sessions do
    get "login" => "sessions#new"
    post "login" => "sessions#create"
    delete "logout" => "sessions#destroy"
end
```

---

```
app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:
# replace this line
<%= form_tag new_session_path do %>
# with
<%= form_tag login_path do %>
```

---

the login link is now:
`<%= link_to "Login", login_path %>`
the logout link:
`<%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, :method => :delete %>`

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply Klump, this seems to have got me a step nearer the only thing now is the following error - undefined local variable or method `logout_path' for #<#<Class:0x4a7b940>:0x4a78928>

Comment: you have to replace `logout_path` and `login_path` with the routes to your action for login/ logout. did you create entries in the routes.rb for those?

Comment: My current routes.rb file is the following: MadeByV2::Application.routes.draw do
  get "user/new"
  get "sessions/new"
  
  
  resources :users, :controller => :user
  resources :sessions

Comment: thats a bit nonsense because `resource :users` should create the route  for `get "user/new". i guess its the sessions controller which is in charge of login and logout? and what actions do you have defined in the sessions controller?

Comment: 'class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end
 
 def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
   session[:user_id] = user.id
   redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
   flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password!"
   render "new"
  end
 end
 
 def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged Out!"
 end
 
end'

Comment: Sorry for the amateur layout on this - I can't get the 'code' function to work in the comments :s

Comment: i guess it does not work in comments :P but you could user backticks like this `some code`
back to topic: you should edit your routes.rb to look like this: http://pastebin.com/bBqQcCKi

Comment: i guess you have to change something in the view for `session/new` the line with form_tag. there should go `login_path` instead of `new_session_path`.

Comment: ha! I couldn't find the backticks key but have now. The change in routes.rb and sessions/new seems to have annoyed webrick which won't start now. I have the following: `<h1>Log In</h1>

<%= form_tag login_path do %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :email %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
 </div>
 
 <div class ="field">
  <%= label_tag :password %>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>
 </div>
 
 <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></div>
<%end%>` in sessions/new

Comment: this seems correct. what is now in your routes.rb? (i guess this is what webrick has the problem with)

Comment: my bad again, I had copied your paste bin stuff exactly and it had an end before the root url - Woohoo I have a logout button now thanks! It doesn't seem to switch and say login though once I have pushed logout?

Comment: do you really get logged out when you press the link? it seems not. can you check that somehow?

Comment: as fast as i can see is your destroy method correct, it should log you out. does the log report any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but this Railscast was very helpful to me in learning about how authentication works in rails.  The Railscast is Twitter login specific using [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) but the process is much the same.  He includes the dynamic links you asked about in his code.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth